# AWS dynamoDB - how to make new attribute (not created at table creation) appear while creating item

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

While creating dynamoDB table, I've mentioned only two attributes. At the time of creating a new item, an extra attribute has been added and it appears in the table.

However while clicking on **create item** in AWS console, the new attribute doesn't appear. Only the attributes added during table creation appears.

How to make this new attribute appear in the create item option?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not code related.

Answer (score 2):

It won't in the console as DynamoDB does not enforce a schema beyond the primary key (either a partition key or a partition+sort keys). Item #1 can have different attributes, beyond the primary key, than Item #2, so they do not appear.

That said, if you use the [NoSQL Workbench for DynamoDB tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html), it has a more tabular view of data and sounds like it will do what you are looking for or close to it.